# How to go inside into the one of the node in K8S

Tags: kubernetes

I have a single node kubernetes cluster running locally in my system AND some pods are running in that cluster.

Now i want to go inside the node and change  directory and do some testing

exactly like this

[image]

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hostpath persistent volume

follow the below steps

1. Create a directory on the host say, /mnt/test-vol
2. add a label to node say, test-vol=y
3. Deploy a pod with hostpath as persistent volume using node selector as test-vol=y
4. the pod gets deployed on the node matching label  test-vol=y
5. now you  should be able to test the test-vol.
6. create some files in /mnt/test-vol on the host
7. you should see those files in the pod that is using /mnt/test-vol as hostpath
8. you can also create or modify the files from pod and the same gets reflected on the node

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22746804)

Comment: added detailed instructions